# scala function returning only single value of list but not all why?

Tags: scala

I tried this
probability function returning only single value of list but not all why

```
var l=List(2.2,3.1)
def sum(xs: List[Double]): Double=
{
  if(xs.isEmpty) 0.0
  else xs.head+sum(xs.tail)
}
var s=sum(l)
def probability_calculation( xs: List[Double], s:Double): List[Double]=
{
  var p=List[Double]()
  var R=2
  if(xs.isEmpty) List()
  else
  {
    p=p:::List(xs.head*R/s)
    probability_calculation(xs.tail,s)
  }
  p
}

probability_calculation(l,s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-initializing the list on every recursion:

```
var p=List[Double]()
```

So your final result list will only contain the last element.

I don't see the need for the recursion, you could just map it:

```
def probability_calculation(xs: List[Double], s: Double): List[Double] = {
  val R = 2

  xs.map(x => x * R / s)
}
```

Comment: thanx for consideration

Answer (score 2):

A few comments on your approach!

Try avoiding using var's in your function as that is exactly the source of your problem that you are facing!

Also, your sum function could be written as simple as:

```
val sum = List(2.2, 3.1).foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _)
```

Your probability distribution function could be written as:

```
def probCaclculation(xs: List[Double], s: Double): List[Double] = xs.map(x => x * 2 / s)
```

Comment: Don't really need the pattern `match`. Just `map` the `List`. If it's empty that's what's returned.

Comment: thanx for consideration